# Does anyone know what I did wrong with this formula? I want to have all "IF" statements, plus one "IF AND" statement

Tags: if-statement

I'm trying to show the results if the value in X2 is below minimum, at minimum, above maximum, or between upper third and max. That is easy, but to cover the part that is between the upper 1/3 and maximum I tried adding an "IF AND" statement but it doesn't work.

=IF(AND(X2=AK2,X2<AL2),"Hired Upper Third"),(IF(X2<AH2,"Hired Below Min",IF(X2=AH2,"Hired at Min",IF(X2>=AL2,"Hired at Max or Above"," "))))

I tried pasting the cells of the spreadsheet I'm working on, but it isn't letting me.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a proper problem description. Does it show an error? Does it show an unexpected result? What software are you even talking about?

Comment: I'm using Excel. The error message is #VALUE!